# SQL Table Integrity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2014 but I'm looking for a design solution.

I have 3 tables that I need to connect together to ensure integrity. I'm removed some tables and columns for the sake of clarity.

[image]

Group is the parent of type.

```
Group: Widgets
Types: Blue Widgets, Red Widgets
```

I want to store data at Group/Category level, for instance:

```
Group: Widgets
Categories: Widgets for men, Widgets for women
```

Categories should be contrained at Type level

```
Type: Blue Widgets
Category: Widgets for men

Type: Red Widgets
Category: Widgets for women
```

Therefore I'm trying to ensure the data I enter into TypeCat is valid in that the Category and the Type's Group exist in GroupCat.

I'm sure there is some kind of pattern for this, however as a non DB guy, I'm not sure how to work this out.

Comment: Have a look at Foreign Keys, they should do what you're after

Comment: You're right Rich , but I'm struggling to find the right combination that will ensure the necessary interity.

Comment: So you want an FK from GroupCat to TypeCat for blue/red widgets. You then want an FK from Typecat to GroupType to show widgets for men/widgets for women?

Comment: I think were still missing something Rich, I'm going to set up a test on my system but I don't think the 2 constraints are enough

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of spending far too much time on your question, I'm going to try to show you how difficult it is to untangle.  You use a thicket of abstract nouns -- type, category, group -- in varying combinations.  You change nomenclature between the illustrated tables and the question text.  You don't state what the keys are.  Then you make some declarations, and expect the reader to make the right associations and inferences.

> Group is the parent of type.

So `GroupID` identifies `GroupType`; thus a GroupType has a TypeID.  Anyway, that's how I'd interpret "parent".

> Categories should be contrained at Type level

I wasn't able to make sense of that given the next statement:

> ensure the data I enter into TypeCat is valid in that the Category and the Type's Group exist in GroupCat

Not sure what "that" category is, but the rule seems to be

```
TypeCat.TypeID exists in GroupType.TypeID
GroupType.GroupID exists in GroupCat.GroupID
```

But you also said

> I want to store data at Group/Category level

which would seem to imply the new data are coming from the left, as it were, and that new rows in `GroupCat` must meet certain constraints:

```
GroupCat.GroupID exists in GroupType.GroupID -- opposite above
GroupCat.CatID   exists in TypeCat.CatID
{GroupCat.GroupID,TypeCat.TypeID} exists in GroupType
```

Those rules *can* be expressed in SQL, but I'm not sure they should.  And I'm not sure they're what you intend.  I'm throwing darts and, if not exactly blindfolded, let's say the lighting leaves something to be desired.

In general, the statement `A must have a B` in SQL means there is a table B representing the domain of values of its type, and a foreign key on a column in A whose values must come from that domain.  By that logic, there should be tables for Groups, Categories, and Types in your model.  The pattern of the last rule above -- where two tables must be joined to determine if they meet a third domain -- does occur, but *rarely*.  When it crops up, it's usually cause to look things over carefully and ensure that the model really does reflect reality.